# Firebase: get pathname after redirect

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I want to create a website which will work on any pathname, like `domain.com/abc`, `domain.com/xyz` and so on.

But I want to serve from home page only. The content will be generated dynamically.

I think it is possible using `firebase.json` file, but how do I do that?

I have tried `redirect`, but that didn't work as pathname wasn't preserved.

Answer (score 1):

This should be configured by default, but here you go:

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Add the "rewrites" attribute within "hosting"
  "rewrites": [ {
    // Serves index.html for requests to files or directories that do not exist
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
}
```

The appropriate section in the [documentation can be found here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites).

This (`rewrites`) will serve content from the specified `destination` but ***not*** redirect to another URL.